# Is there a way to activate webGL in Qt Jambi Webkit ?

Tags: java, qt, webgl, qt-jambi

Is there a way to activate webGL in Qt Jambi Webkit ? 
I find no one who talk about this on the web, no one who ask the question, no one who say "no".

Answer (score 0):

That's mostly a matter of Qt version used by the bindings.

`QWebEngineView` of Qt 5.7 or newer should be able to do WebGL and have it enabled by default.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum

Comment: Ok, QtJambi is using Qt 4.8.6. So no WebGL with QtJambi. 
Thanks for the information.